# Round number by rounding units in R

Tags: r, rounding

I am trying to round number by rounding units.

For example,

```
value <- c(8.21,1.76, 6.42,1.94,10.38)
```

if rounding unit is 0.2, the results would be

```
(8.2, 1.8, 6.4, 2.0, 10.4).
```

How can I do it in R? Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Your result is wrong. That's 1.9, not 2.0. Try `round(value, 1)`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik 1.94 is closer to 2.0 than 1.8, which is what I think the OP means by 0.2 as the rounding unit.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I guess I must have damaged my crystal ball when I dropped it yesterday. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
round.to <- function(x, b) {
  round(x/b)*b
}

round.to(value, .2)
## [1]  8.2  1.8  6.4  2.0 10.4
```

This technique also works for b>1:

```
round.to(value, 2)
## [1]  8  2  6  2 10
```