# Round number to non-zero value

Tags: r, rounding

I am looking for something partially along the line of this

[Round number by rounding units in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268771/round-number-by-rounding-units-in-r)

I want to have a function which automatically rounds a number smaller than 1 to a non-zero value e.g.

0.0043----> 0.004

0.087 ---> 0.09

but in general I do not know how many zero decimals I have in each number, so I cannot resort to a plain vanilla round().
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Do you mean [Significant Digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526038/how-to-format-numbers-in-r-specifying-the-number-of-significant-digits-but-keep)?

Comment: I assume that the problem is that you can not formalize the criteria to the rounding. Try to specify what exactly you need: the number of decimals, the number of non-zero digits etc. Probably the answer will vary for different data fields

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42959616/rounding-significant-figures-in-r

Comment: Indeed significant digits are the way to go for me! Thanks.